# Question about the number of subsets

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Given a set $S$ of size $25$, let $x$ be an element in $S$. What is the number of subsets of $S$ that contain $x$?

Why am I stuck on this?
The number of subsets that don't contain $x$ is $2^{24}$, correct? I don't how to figure out if $x$ is in a subset..
The options given are: 
$2^{24}$
$2^{25} - 25$
$2^{25} - 1$
None of the above

Comment: What exactly is the question? It seems that you already know the answer. What do you mean by "I don't how to figure out if x is a subset .."?

Comment: Every subset of $S$ containing $x$ can be written as $\{x\}\cup T$ where $T$ is a subset of $S$ *not* containing $x$. Also note that $2^{25}-2^{24}=2^{24}$

Comment: @drhab ohh, thank you for that extra note. It was confusing to me that the number that doesn't contain x and the number that does contain x was the same but that makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is correct. You've split up the subset into two families: Those that contain $x$ and those that do not. There are $2^{25}$ subsets in total, and $2^{24}$ of them do not contain $x$; how many are left?

When stuck on a question like this it might be helpful to consider a concrete example that's possible to work out explicitly (while being general enough to work in the case that you're interested in). For instance, try working out what would happen if instead $S$ consisted of $3$ points, say $S = \{1,2,3\}$ and $x = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

It's $2^{24}$, and it's the same number than the number of subsets that doesn't contain X actually. A way to see it :

If you think of a subset as its caracteristic function ($1_S(x)=1$ if $x \in S$, $0$ else) then you see that imposing $x \in S$ just impose that $1_S(x)=1$. It leaves you the choice for the remaining $24$ elements to set $0$ or $1$ (id est belonging or not), so $2^{24}$. You see that the condition $x \not \in X$ impose $1_X(x)=0$, and also leaves you $2^{24}$ choices.

An other way to say the same thing at sets level, is to see that subsets that contain $x$ and subsets that don't are in a bijective correspondance by $S \mapsto S \cup \{x\}$ and its inverse $S \mapsto S \setminus \{x\}$. So the number of such sets is the same, and since it's a partition of subsets of $X$ (either you contain $x$ or you don't), then you have $2.c=2^{25}$ so $c=2^{24}$